# mergesort using 2 thread ID's

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mergesort

hi i want to use mergesort to an array using threads i need to use two thread id in order to sort recursionly
here is my code

```
void Recursive_Divition(int a[], int l, int h,int Degree_of_parallelism,int count)//this function divdis recursivly the array 
 {//and sends it to merge sort
struct thread_data thread_data_array[Degree_of_parallelism];
int i, len=(h-l+1);

// Using insertion sort for small sized array
if (len==2*Degree_of_parallelism)//a stoping condition if the array size is equal to the degree of parallisim then send the array to be sortrd
{


    pthread_t * thread = (pthread_t *)malloc(Degree_of_parallelism*sizeof(pthread_t ));//creating a pointer to thread array

    thread_data_array[count].low=l;//the arguments for the merge sort
    thread_data_array[count].high=h/2;



    pthread_create(&thread[count],NULL,threaded_merge_sort,(void *) &thread_data_array[count]);//create a thread and send it to the function
    count++;
    thread_data_array[count].low=h/2+1;//the argument for the other thread
    thread_data_array[count].high=h;

    pthread_create(&thread[count],NULL,threaded_merge_sort,(void *) &thread_data_array[count]);
    pthread_join(thread[count-1],NULL);
     pthread_join(thread[count],NULL);
    free(thread);

    }

if(len>Degree_of_parallelism){

    Recursive_Divition(a,l,l+len/2-1,Degree_of_parallelism,count);//for the first half

    Recursive_Divition(a,l+len/2,h,Degree_of_parallelism,count);//for the secound half
    merge(a, l, l+len/2-1, h);
}
```

}
and here is the threaded merge sort

```
void *threaded_merge_sort(void *param) 
 {
   printf("Create a thread %u\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());//this           function calls the merge sort function
   struct thread_data *my_data;

   my_data = (struct thread_data *) param;
   int l=my_data->low;
  int h=my_data->high;
  printf("low is : %d high is : %d\n",l,h);
  mergeSort(array,l,h);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
```

and i got the following output the problem appears to be in the index and i didn't know how to fix it

> ```
> Amount of numbers that sort: 16
> Degree of parallelism: 8
> Array Before Sort: 1,5,6,33,77,12,90,87,0,10,34,2,741,453,19,132
> Create a thread 3158492928
> low is : 0 high is : 1
> Create a thread 3150100224
> low is : 2 high is : 3
> Create a thread 3141707520
> low is : 4 high is : 3
> Create a thread 3133314816
> low is : 4 high is : 7
> Create a thread 3122734848
> low is : 8 high is : 5
> Create a thread 3114342144
> low is : 6 high is : 11
> Create a thread 3105949440
> Create a thread 3097556736
> low is : 8 high is : 15
> low is : 12 high is : 7
> Array After Sort: 1,5,6,10,19,33,12,34,0,2,77,87,90,132,453,741
> ```

Comment: I haven't completely worked it out, but it appears likely that your indexing is going wrong in the `if(len>Degree_of_parallelism)` block.

Comment: ya the problem is with the indexing and i didn't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The indexing problem is here:

> ```
>     thread_data_array[count].low=l;//the arguments for the merge sort
>     thread_data_array[count].high=h/2;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>     thread_data_array[count].low=h/2+1;//the argument for the other thread
>     thread_data_array[count].high=h;
> ```

That does not correctly split the (sub)array into halves unless `l` is 0.  For example, if `h` is 16 then your array break is always at 8, even if that's less than `l`.

Instead, you appear to want

```
    thread_data_array[count].low = l;
    thread_data_array[count].high= (l + h) / 2;
```

and

```
    thread_data_array[count].low = (l + h) / 2 + 1;
    thread_data_array[count].high=h;
```

Also, I suspect you want an `else` before the second `if` in `Recursive_Divition()`, and you may also need to add final `else` block.